# Change Word Color

Tags: arduino-uno

I tried to change the color of the words but nothing happens, I do not know what I'm doing wrong. I am using official Arduino editor of code with words.txt

```
#######################################
# Syntax Coloring Map For testing
#######################################

#######################################
# Datatypes (KEYWORD1)
#######################################

Test    KEYWORD1 
Diego   KEYWORD1
Ulises  KEYWORD1
PALMA   KEYWORD1 

#######################################
# Methods and Functions (KEYWORD2)
#######################################

doSomething KEYWORD2
Argentina   KEYWORD2
Brasil      KEYWORD2
Alemania    KEYWROD2
Chile       KEYWORD2

#######################################
# Instances (KEYWORD2)
#######################################

#######################################
# Constants (LITERAL1)
#######################################
```

Comment: The of this page www.Arduino.cc

Comment: ARDUINO 1.8.3, es aquí https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/Software

Comment: An IDE is a tool that helps us to develop our applications in a friendly way

Comment: is the editor of code

Comment: I'm sorry my communication in English is not perfect .. Arduino ide or Arduino Aide I was referring to using the text editor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question's reference to “official Arduino with words.txt” is rather ambiguous.  So far there has not been any clarification whether the question refers to the usual *Arduino IDE* environment.

However, supposing the question intended to refer to the usual environment, note that the [Library Tutorial](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Hacking/LibraryTutorial) document at arduino.cc says to do the following to set up a list of highlighted keywords:

> Create a file called **keywords.txt** in the [library] directory

Thus, renaming your *words.txt* to *keywords.txt* may solve the problem.

Comment: Just to clarify, tabs need to be used as separators in the keywords.txt file, as spaces will not work.